# How do I detect if the user bought my app?

Tags: objective-c

I've recently submitted my App to the AppStore(Waiting for review ;) and I want to be able to detect if there's a metadata file on /var/mobile/Applications/MyApp.app/iTunesMetaData.plist

if there is one, the app has been bought, if there isn't, the app has been pirated. now my main question is : Will apple allow this? I've seen some posts about apps with Jailbreak detection being declined from the App store.

Second, Can I do it with this code?

```
NSString *filePath = @"/Var/Mobile/Applications/SystemOfADown.app/iTunesMetaData.plist";
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
// AlertView or killall this app

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really think piracy detection is that simple? What would prevent someone copying your app from just putting an iTunesMetadata.plist file there?

Comment: If they'd make all that effort just to save €1.79 then they deserve it :p

Comment: Oh damn, I now call the alertview or killall if the path DOES exist. I of course meant to call it in else. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it. You are only checking if a file exists. There are many apps in the App Store that display an alert if the app is pirated.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [Crackify](https://github.com/itruf/crackify). It does what you want. With Crackify you can check if your app has been cracked. Never used it, though, so I don't know if it works all the time.